# Why my HTTP request fail from PHP?

Tags: php, http-post

I try to submit a form to remote server: http://openconvert.clarin.inl.nl/openconvert/tagger#text, as you can see the required fileds are `input` and `format`, and the action url is `http://openconvert.clarin.inl.nl/openconvert/text/`, so I try the following in php:

```
<?php
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => $data
  ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
$remoteurl="http://openconvert.clarin.inl.nl/openconvert/text";
$rawdata=array(
  'input'=>'test',
  'format'=>'text');
$data=http_build_query($rawdata, '', '&amp;'); //flags_, myvar_
var_dump($data);
echo "<br />";
echo do_post_request($remoteurl,$data,'Content-Type: text/html');
?>
```

I don't know why the server can't find my data?

The output is:

```
string(26) "input=test&amp;format=text"
<br /><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>Insufficient parameters. Required parameters: input, format</error>
```

Comment: Also, I find a online HTTP request, the resluts is the same as my php: https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: Looks like you have some problem in your do post request function call. Probably you are receiving that as server response for soap or restfull call if at all that function you calling has it. Can you post that as well?

Comment: I find the error cased by the header `Content-Type: text/html`, just use the default: `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will work.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other problems, but the `&amp;` value in http_build_query is definitely wrong. You're not embedding your urlencoded data into an html document, so you should not html-escape the ampersand. Replacing that line with:

```
http_build_query($rawdata, '', '&amp;');
```

should be better, but it might not be 100% of your solution.

P.S.: Don't use `@`, ever. You are suppressing real errors that you *should* see.